# os.listdir как правильно прописать путь в Windows

Tags: python, windows, файловая-система, python-2.7

Код:

```
path_dir = 'C:\path_to_dir'
  for name in os.listdir(path_dir):
    foo
```

Ошибка:
    for name in os.listdir(dir):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\path_to_dir'

Как правильно прописать путь?

Comment: Слеши в строках программ нужно экранировать: `'C:\\path_to_dir'`. Можно еще так: `'C:/path_to_dir'`

Comment: Другой вариант: поставить ``r`` перед строкой - ``r'C:\path_to_dir'``

Comment: Это не помогает,  'C:\\path_to_dir'  ->  OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\\\path_to_dir'

Comment: r перед путем тоже не помогло(

Comment: Попробуй так`path = 'C:\\path_to_dir\\'`

Comment: `'C:\\\\path_to_dir'` - похоже вы и слеши задвоили, и r перед строкой добавили. Нужно или одно, или другое сделать, но не оба варианта сразу.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
path_dir = r'C:\Python37'
for name in os.listdir(path_dir):
    print(name)
```

Comment: Символ r тоже не помогает

Comment: @Сканави если ничего не помогает, значит остается только вариант, что этого пути у вас не существует.